# R.Java issues when switching computers

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

When I am switching between my laptop and desktop, both windows 7, both 64 bit, both have the exact same user name and folder names, R.Java cannot be resolved. It is however being generated perfectly, and if I include it in each java file it works perfectly.

I just don't want to have to include the file everytime. Is there a reason why the R.Java file would be generated, but not included automatically in an Android project? I have gone through the Java Buildpaths and project settings. Everything seems to be the exact same though I may have missed something subtle.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the project (right click on project -> refresh)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of possibilities:

1. If the resource compiler encounters an error, R.java won't be generated. Check that the resources compile cleanly.
2. The Java build path may not have been set up properly in the new environment, or the Android SDK installation may be set up differently.

You may just need to clean and build your project.

Comment: Somehow I missed that my packages had been duplicated. One package was fine, the other needed R.java imported. I deleted the second set, cleaned and it's working fine now. Dunno how I missed that.